# HTML5 Video Player Progress Bar Accurate Tooltip

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, html5-video

Most video players allow you to click on the progress bar to jump to a particular point in the video by using the position of the mouse on the progress bar to roughly work out what point in the video the user will skip to if the progress bar is clicked at that point.

If the progress bar max value is small the calculation is correct.

This is an example:

```js
$("#range").on("click", function(event){
    var tooltip = Math.round((event.offsetX / event.target.clientWidth) * parseInt(event.target.getAttribute('max')));
    if (tooltip < 0) {
        tooltip = 0
    }else if (tooltip > 10) {
        tooltip = 10
    } 
    $(".calculated").text("Calculated Value: " + tooltip)
    $(".real").text("Real Value: " + $(this).val())
});
```

```css
.main{
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 50px
}

/* Tooltip text */
.main .tooltip {
  width: 120px;
  background-color: #555;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px;
  border-radius: 6px;
}

input{
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main">
    <span class="tooltip calculated">5</span>
    <span class="tooltip real">20</span>
    <input type="range" min="0" max="10" value="20" id="range">
</div>
```

But if the progress bar max value is big the calculation will not be exact.

This is an example:

```js
$("#range").on("click", function(event){
    var tooltip = Math.round((event.offsetX / event.target.clientWidth) * parseInt(event.target.getAttribute('max')));
    if (tooltip < 0) {
        tooltip = 0
    }else if (tooltip > 1000) {
        tooltip = 1000
    } 
    $(".calculated").text("Calculated Value: " + tooltip)
    $(".real").text("Real Value: " + $(this).val())
});
```

```css
.main{
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 50px
}

/* Tooltip text */
.main .tooltip {
  width: 120px;
  background-color: #555;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px;
  border-radius: 6px;
}

input{
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main">
    <span class="tooltip calculated">20</span>
    <span class="tooltip real">20</span>
    <input type="range" min="0" max="1000" value="20" id="range">
</div>
```

Is there any other solution to get more accurate calculation ? I'm happy to hear any suggestions.

Comment: Try logging `event.offsetX` to the console to see why the calculations are not what you expect. Sounds like an XY-Problem. What are you trying to do?

Comment: Yes the problem is that the pixels number are lesser than the video duration, So it's normal getting inexact calculation. There is nothing wrong about `event.offsetX`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why there is so much error in the calculation you attempted is everything but obvious.

You correctly identified an imprecision with a big `maxValue` on a short slider width.

The calculation error comes from the fact that the range slider knotches are not distributed in a linear way from left to right. So a simple division of the `offsetX` by the slider's width is... incomplete.

The "thumb" of the slider has a width. So in order to be able to get the minimum and maximum values while keeping the thumb inside the slider, the knotches are distributed in a way to gradually compensate that width from the extremes (+/-50% of thumb width) to the middle (0% of thumb width). In other words, the middle really is the middle value... But the exteme knotches are "offsetted" with a percentage of the thumb width.

---

To the `span` you used to show the calculated value versus the "real" one, I added a span for the difference in calculation and one for the error percentage. So as you can see below, I achieved a maximal error percentage of around 0.10% or less... I really doubt it is possible to get better than this! ;)

So to make sure that my calculation is tight here, I used a super huge range of ten millions (lol!)... And tried to come with the most accurate calculation possible. There always will be an error... But the idea is to keep it minimal AND "consistant" all over the slider width.

Since the key is about the thumb width, I added some CSS took from [css-tricks](https://css-tricks.com/styling-cross-browser-compatible-range-inputs-css/) just to make sure about that width. Removing that styling does not change anything (at least on Chrome). I did NOT found a way to retreive the slider's thumb width programmatically. So your simple solution is to define it.

I hope the calculations below are clear.

```js
$("#range").on("click", function(event) {

  // Get the slider's params
  let maxValue = parseInt(event.target.getAttribute('max'))
  let sliderWidth = event.target.clientWidth

  // That is the key value causing offsets in calculations
  let thumbWidth = 16

  // I made a named function just to have the calculation logic apart from the rest.
  let thumbCorrection = getOffsetXcorrection(event.offsetX, sliderWidth, thumbWidth)

  // Using that "thumb correction" in the basic intuitive calculation anyone would expect
  let clickedKnotch = (event.offsetX-thumbCorrection) / sliderWidth
  
  
  // The demo outputs
  var calculatedValue = Math.round(clickedKnotch * maxValue)
  let realValue = $(this).val()
  let difference = calculatedValue - realValue
  let errorPercentage = Math.abs((difference / maxValue) *100)

  $(".calculated").text("Calculated: " + calculatedValue)
  $(".real").text("Real: " + realValue)
  $(".difference").text("Diff: " + difference)
  $(".percentage").text("Error: " + errorPercentage.toFixed(2) + "%")
});


function getOffsetXcorrection(clickedPosition, fullWidth, thumbWidth) {
  
  // The middle is the 0% correction point
  let middle = fullWidth/2
  
  // The "error" always is about half the thumb width
  let halfThumbWidth = thumbWidth/2
  
  // So where occured the click in that context?
  let percentageFromMiddle = (middle - clickedPosition) / middle
  
  // Return the correction about the click position to use in a "linear" calculation
  let correction = percentageFromMiddle * halfThumbWidth
  return Math.round(correction)
}
```

```css
.main {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 50px
}


/* Tooltip text */

.main .tooltip {
  width: 120px;
  background-color: #555;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px;
  border-radius: 6px;
}

input {
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 1em;
}

/* From CSS-tricks */
input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  border: 0px solid #000000;
  height: 16px;
  width: 16px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  /*background: #ffffff;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-top: -14px;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000000, 0px 0px 1px #0d0d0d; */
}

.main .percentage{
  background-color: tomato;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main">
  <span class="tooltip calculated">20</span>
  <span class="tooltip real">20</span>
  <span class="tooltip difference">0</span>
  <span class="tooltip percentage">0</span>
  <input type="range" min="0" max="10000000" value="20" id="range">
</div>
```

Comment: Why the error gets so much bigger if you move the thumb to the start or the end of the slider.

Comment: That is because the `click` event occurs when the mouse button is released. So while dragging the thumb to zero, if the mouse release occurs when the mouse is not over the thumb, the calculation is off.

Comment: Maybe you should only use the real value with the `input` event... Instead of `click`. But I don't know what you really want to do with the tooltip.

Comment: Even if the click isn't in the real start. the error occurs in the first let's say 20px of the range slider. The problem isn't from the release of the mouse.

Comment: The question was a simple example. What I really want to do with the tooltip is to preview the time of the video player on `rangeslider` mousemove

Comment: Okay. Since you now have the most exact calculation, your fun begins with playing with the other possible events. In [this CodePen](https://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/LYbdVJP), I added `mouseenter, mousemove and mouseleave` to play with the displayed tooltips. Notice the `if(event.type...` conditions. I also added a way to limit the calculated value within the min and max values. Have a look! ;)

Comment: Just *WOW*. Even the most famous video players doesn't have this exact calculation !!

Comment: Loll. Thanks. Now it is time for you to style the slider track, thumb and the tooltip of course. Because out of 100 people, just one may really notice the super accuracy while the 99 other will just notice the visual styling. You can do both! ;) I would love to see the final result, if you can post a link someday.... Happy coding!

Comment: I will ! And you will like it ! I'm a UI/UX Designer.

Answer (score 1):

Because of the width of the point.

[image]

In the picture above, the actual length of the input is (100% - point's width)

Although it is possible to calculate simply by excluding the length of the dot, it is not recommended because errors may occur depending on the screen width or browser type.

My solution is to use percentages.

```
$("#range").on("click", function(event) {
    var inputVal = parseInt(event.target.value);
    var inputMaxVal = parseInt(event.target.getAttribute("max"));
    var inputPercentage = inputVal / inputMaxVal * 100;

    var tmpVideo = document.getElementById("yourVideo");
    var videoDur = tmpVideo.duration;
    var videoCur = tmpVideo.currentTime;
    var videoPercentage = videoCur / videoDur * 100;

    $(".calculated").text("Calculated Value: " + inputPercentage);
    $(".real").text("Real Value: " + videoPercentage);
});
```

Now compare the inputPercentage and videoPercentage.

p.s. I may have misunderstood the problem because I am using a translator.